# Join with Where clause in hql

Tags: hibernate, hql

My sql query is

```
select count(tid) from admin.details tcd 
inner join admin.module tm on tcd.moduleid=tm.module where
 tm.bankid=1234 and roundid=2 and tm.status=true
```

How to get the same output using hql?

I tried this. I am getting syntax error

```
 select count(tid) from Details d join tcd.Module m 
 with d.moduleId=m.moduleId
 where d.bankDetails.bankId = :bid 
 and d.roundMaster.roundId = :rid and m.status=:pid
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: could not resolve property tcd.Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tcd and tid are not defined in your hql query.
I think that you should base your hql to the proper entities, in this way any join will be automatically reached.

Anyway, after having defined the correct @joinColumn property in entities, e.g. in Detail entity there should be something like

```
@JoinColumn(name = "Detail_Module_Id", referencedColumnName = "Module_Id")
private Module moduleId;
```

your hql query should become:

```
select count(tid) from Details d  
where d.bankDetails.bankId = :bid 
and d.roundMaster.roundId = :rid  
and d.moduleId.status= :pid
```

I don't know if d.bankDetails.bankId and d.roundMaster.roundId could work, it depends on how your entities are defined for these columns.
Another way is to use hql native queries, but I don't recommend it.